# Why doesn't this AutoMapper mapping work?

Tags: c#, nunit, automapper

I don't understand why this isn't working? Both fields map to NULL on the destinationDTO.
Using AutoMapper v4.1.1

```
[TestFixture]
public class AutoMapperTests
{
    [SetUp]
    public void Init()
    {
        AutoMapperTestConfiguration.Configure();
    }

    [Test]
    public void Mapping_With_Underscores()
    {
        SourceDTO source = new SourceDTO
        {
            first_name = "John",
            last_name = "Doe"
        };

        var result = Mapper.Map<DestinationDTO>(source);

        Assert.That(result.FirstName == "John");
    }
}


public class SourceDTO
{
    public string first_name { get; set; }
    public string last_name { get; set; }
}

public class DestinationDTO
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}

public class AutoMapperTestConfiguration
{
    public static void Configure()
    {
        Mapper.Initialize(x =>
        {
            x.AddProfile<FromUnderscoreMapping>();
        });
    }
}

public class FromUnderscoreMapping : Profile
{
    protected override void Configure()
    {
        this.SourceMemberNamingConvention = new LowerUnderscoreNamingConvention();
        this.DestinationMemberNamingConvention = new PascalCaseNamingConvention();

        Mapper.CreateMap<SourceDTO, DestinationDTO>();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Ouch, this bit me for some time. The problem was on this line

```
Mapper.CreateMap<SourceDTO, DestinationDTO>();
```

I was invoking the global AutoMapper instance and not the inherited Profile which has the override for the naming conventions. 
Simply removing Mapper fixed the problem.

```
CreateMap<SourceDTO, DestinationDTO>();
```

I wasted lots of time on this one.